# Wordpress - Attachments block slugs

Tags: wordpress, attachment, conflict, slug

**Summary:** Some uploaded attachments automatically get slugs I later want to use for posts. It is impossible to change them without database access and very annoying.

Hi everyone,

I am using wordpress and lately uploaded some images.

Subsequently I was trying to create a post with a certain slug but wordpress automatically added a "-2" to it, indicating that there was already a page using the slug.

I entered the slug into my browser and it redirected me to an image I had uploaded. Weird.
I entered phpMyAdmin and searched the database for posts with the slug.
( `SELECT * FROM wp_posts w where post_name like 'my-desired-slug';` )
In the database I found an entry of an object with post_type = "attachment". It has the desired slug assigned to it ("post_name"="my-desired-slug")

It is weird that wordpress assigned the slug to an attachment. This function is very unpractical. Now I had to edit the slug in the database since wordpress does not offer a UI section to edit attachment slugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the admin you can go to Media, then select a image. In the detail page on the bottom right you can click "Edit more details". In the following screen below the title you can change the permalink!

Comment: Thank you. I am pleased to see, there IS a way to edit this in the WP backend.

Answer (score 0):

Attachments block slugs on Wordpress

add this code to your themes/function.php:

``

```
add_filter( 'attachment_link', 'remove_post_slug_from_attachment_link', 10, 2 );
function remove_post_slug_from_attachment_link( $link, $post_id ) {
    $post = get_post( $post_id );
    $parent = get_post( $post->post_parent );
    if ( $parent && $parent->post_type != 'post' ) {
        $link = preg_replace( '/\/' . $parent->post_name . '\//', '/', $link );
    }
    return $link;
}
```

``